# How many versions of a gem can I install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm having this problem where I run `gem install -v=2.3.12 rails` and the cli tells me it installed successfully. But when I run `gem list rails` it's not in the list of available rails versions.

I'm not sure why this isn't working, but I've noticed that for every gem in the list, there's no more than 6 versions of a specific gem. Is there a limit for the number of versions you can have for a specific gem?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a limit for the number of versions you can have for a
>   specific gem

There is no limit for the number of version for a specific gem in docs: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/2 You can use `gem list` to see all you gems installed.